# Error with comparison between fgets() to string

Tags: php

I have some file (m.php) that I've just this inside (There is nothing else!):

```
000
```

and I have more page with this source:

```
$file = fopen('m.php', 'a+');
$line = fgets($file);
if ($line == "000") { echo "there is equal"; }
fclose($file);
```

Why in the `if` i did not get the "there is equal" ? (it mean: 000 != 000)

but if i do 'echo $line;' , its print to me: 000

Comment: From the [documentation](http://php.net/fgets): "*Reading ends when length - 1 bytes have been read, or a newline (**which is included in the return value**)*". In other words, `$line` doesn't contain what you think it does. Verify this by checking the output of `var_dump($line);` — add this statement after `$line = fgets($file);`.

Comment: yahh thats was the problem. i solve this

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it like this

```
<?php
    $file = 'm.php';
    $line = file_get_contents($file);
    if ($line == "000") {
        echo "there is equal";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Using file_get_contents() to read a string from a file works in the case of one-line files, but not in a general case...

Answer (score 0):

fgets() returns newline, too... :-)
Please chop results before comparing...

```
<?php
    $file = fopen('m.php', 'a+');
    $line = chop(fgets($file));
    if ($line == "000") {
        echo "there is equal";
    }
    fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: i dont understand what you mean? if i do 'echo $line;', its print to me 000

Comment: Do a var_dump($line) and you will see that it is not 000

Comment: What does `var_dump($line)` print?